# How to remove specific attribute from json object c#

Tags: json, json.net

My JSON object has a pages array and elements array inside it. elements array has many objects .each objects has correct answer attribute

I want to remove the correct answer attribute from the whole JSON.

I tried in this way but I couldn't remove the correct answer attribute.

```
    var o = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ob.Json);
                o.Property("pages").Remove();
```

```
{
 "pages": [
  {
   "name": "page1",
   "elements": [
    {
     "type": "radiogroup",
     "name": "question1",
     "correctAnswer": "item1",
     "choices": [
      "item1",
      "item2",
      "item3"
     ]
    },
    {
     "type": "radiogroup",
     "name": "question2",
     "correctAnswer": "item2",
     "choices": [
      "item1",
      "item2",
      "item3"
     ]
    },
   ]
}
]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete elements from a JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510270/delete-elements-from-a-json)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `JToken.Remove` together with Linq to remove the `correctAnswers`. For example,

```
var jo = JObject.Parse(json);
var answers = jo.Descendants()
           .Where(x => x.Type == JTokenType.Property)
           .Cast<JProperty>()
           .Where(x=>x.Name=="correctAnswer").ToList();
foreach(var answer in answers)
{
    answer.Remove();
}
var filterJson = jo.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *remove* `correctAnswer` property inside that json, you can make a loop for each `element` item and set `correctAnswer` to `null`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Program
{
    class Element
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string correctAnswer { get; set; }
        public IList<string> choices { get; set; }
    }

    class Item
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public IList<Element> elements { get; set; }
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public IList<Item> pages { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var data = "{" +
                "'pages':[" +
                    "{'name':'page1'," +
                    "'elements':[" +
                        "{" +
                            "'type':'radiogroup'," +
                            "'name':'question1'," +
                            "'correctAnswer':'item1'," +
                            "'choices':['item1','item2','item3']" +
                        "}," +
                        "{" +
                            "'type':'radiogroup'," +
                            "'name':'question2'," +
                            "'correctAnswer':'item2'," +
                            "'choices':['item1','item2','item3']" +
                        "}" +
                    "]" +
                    "}]" +
                "}";

            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(data);

            foreach (var page in obj.pages)
            {
                foreach (var element in page.elements)
                {
                    element.correctAnswer = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Another way, in this example, we can remove `correctAsnwer` property from the class `Element`. Then the result after parsing the string to json object, `correctAnswer` property won't be accessed.

```
class Element
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    // public string correctAnswer { get; set; }
    public IList<string> choices { get; set; }
}
```