# C# Unable to remove child objects inside an object

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to remove all childs that contain the word "Water" inside "paths" from my json.

```json
{
  "monday":{},
  "paths": {
    "Apple": {
      "post": {}
    },
    "Water": {
      "post": {}
    },
    "WaterSpot": {
      "post": {}
    }
  }
}
```

My code:

```cs
JObject root = JObject.Parse(my_json);
JObject paths = (JObject)root["paths"];

var childs = paths.Descendants().ToList();

foreach (var item in childs)
{
    if (!item.ToString().Contains("Water"))
    {
        item.Remove();
    }

}
```

Newtonsoft doesn't show how to do that https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm
And this answer doesn't work for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/59839524/13741865

What can I do?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani that produces the error: `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'JToken' because it is not a delegate type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing for sure, you cannot use foreach loop to update the list you are iterating over.
Following is one way of updating the `paths` object to remove the paths and entire branch that contains a specific string.

```
paths.Properties()
    .Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Water"))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => paths.Remove(x.Name));
```

If you try to get all the paths and then only remove the Descendants that contains "water" in the keys, then it will only remove the parent key and not the descendants from under those branches.

You can add the line to get the Descendants after the paths have been filtered. The following will only show the descendants of the paths that do not contain Water in the key.

```
var childs = paths.Descendants().ToList();
```